# Funnel restrictive analysis with groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I am trying to create a funnel analysis with the following conditions. I want to know how many people which enter to the home a page make a search (number of people which make search / number of people which make a home search) and the number of people which make a buy from those which make a search but must be necessary from those people which make first a home (event).

And after this i want to add a new condition that each individual must complete the funnel (or until the further step for each person) in an hour.

For example:

```
df

id  day   time   event
 1   20  16:00    home
 1   20  16:20  search
 1   20  16:25     buy
 2   20  17:00    home
 2   20  17:02    home
 2   20  17:03    home
 2   20  17:06  search
 2   20  17:06  search
 3   21   9:00  search
 4   20   8:00    home
 4   21   8:00  search
 5   22   7:00    home
 5   22   7:15     buy
```

result must be

```
  result

  home   4
search   3
   buy   1
```

explanation of result: home: id1,id2,id4,id5 are ids which make the first step of the funnel that is home (that why the 4 in home)
                     search: id1,id2,id4 are ids which make first home as event and also make a search in less than an hour 
                       buy: only id1 make the funnel complete in order in less than an hour

Answer (score 0):

I've used groupby and str.contains to match your events and count them. Hopefully this will help with the first part of your question.

First I created a sample dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], 'event': ['home', 
    'home', 'search', 'home', 'home', 'search', 'search', 'buy']})
df = df.set_index('id')


     event
id        
1     home
1     home
1   search
2     home
3     home
3   search
3   search
3      buy
```

Then we groupby the ids and sum with

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Then we can use `str.contains` to match your cases

```
ps = ['home', 'homesearch', r'home(search)+buy']
print(pd.DataFrame([df.event.str.contains(p).sum() for p in ps], index=ps))
```

which creates (You can use whatever you like for the index I just used the search string)

```
                  0
home              3
homesearch        2
home(search)+buy  1
```

Note that I had to use regex to match the more complicated case when multiple searches happened before a buy.